# To configure .wsdl for using

Tags: .net, wsdl, app-config, config

I have connected `.wsdl` file to my project (by `adding service reference`). `Wcf` described by `.wsdl` has had configurations without which it can't be ised in my project.
What should I do to set up these configurations?
Any comments, please.

Comment: Are you asking how to enable a WSDL for a WCF service (so that other programs can use a WCF service you have created) or how to consume a WCF service as a client provided you have the WSDL for it?

Comment: I need to use 'wsdl' in my 'WCF service'

Comment: I hope you meant "Add Service Reference". "Add Web Reference" should only be used if absolutely necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look in the project where you did the `add web reference` it should have added app.config entries automatically. All you would need to do is copy them from that config to the config file of the WCF app that is consuming it.

If it did not you can also use [Svcutil](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa347733.aspx) to generate the classes and the configuration. If you have a local copy of the WSDL you can run this command: `svcutil *.wsdl *.xsd /language:C#` or if you importing via a http hosted endpoint this would work `svcutil http://service/metadataEndpoint`.